# Angularjs slow to load templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some which doesn't really do much, still it does really take the longest time to load. I have written the code down for you all to see:

**app.js**

```
var simple = "simple test";
  angular.module('CRTapp', []).controller('ItemController', function() {
    this.item = simple;
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="item" ng-controller="ItemController as item">
{{item.simple}}  
</div>
```

Sometimes people are having to wait nearly a second to see:

```
{{item.simple}}
```

before

```
simple test
```

appears but this is a very long time for some of you to have to wait. Waiting is ok for me but sometimes Jake gets impatient so I can make the HTML page load slowly if you like, but I do not want my Mr Stretchy to become sad when he sees a template before his own special website for his adventures in the Candy Kingdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delay is the time angular library gets to parse your HTML. You can use `ng-bind` instead:

```
<div id="item" 
     ng-controller="ItemController as item"
     ng-bind="item.simple">
</div>
```

This way, your page won't get polluted while angular loads its content.

Comment: You can also check if angular.js is your first library in your <head> element

Comment: Isn't HEAD a thing on Github? I always put my script libraries at the bottom of the page. It's best practice to speed up page load times.

Comment: I mean the place where you wrote `<script src="...angular.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, I don't put that in the head element. It's best not to, as a general rule.

Comment: Very nice, charlietfl. I like yr style.